# PDF Signing With Pkcs11Interop

Tags: c#, pdf, digital-signature, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

I try to use Pkcs11Interop library for our institutional project. But problem is, when i try to get value from token card, "attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt" error is getting from Pkcs11Interop. I couldn't find any solution. Please help me, thank you in advance.

Project is windows form application which is written with .Net Framework 4.5

**Error:** `system.accessviolationexception {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}`

**Error Stack Trace:**

```
 at Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI40.Session.GetAttributeValue(ObjectHandle objectHandle, List`1 attributes)
   at Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI40.Session.GetAttributeValue(ObjectHandle objectHandle, List`1 attributes)
   at EFinImza.Program.Main() in c:\HttpRoot\EFinImza\EFinImza\Program.cs:line 56
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**Code is like this:**

```
static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            string pkcs11Library = @"C:\Windows\System32\akisp11.dll";
            using (var pkcs11 = new Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI40.Pkcs11(pkcs11Library, false, false))
            {
                LibraryInfo info = pkcs11.GetInfo();
                foreach (Slot slot in pkcs11.GetSlotList(false))
                {
                    SlotInfo slotInfo = slot.GetSlotInfo();
                    if (slotInfo.SlotFlags.TokenPresent)
                    {
                        TokenInfo tokenInfo = slot.GetTokenInfo();

                        Session session = slot.OpenSession(false);
                        String pin = "*****";
                        session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, pin);

                        // get all objects using empty ObjectAttributes list
                        List<ObjectHandle> handles = session.FindAllObjects(new List<ObjectAttribute>());
                        List<CKA> attrs = new List<CKA>();
                        attrs.Add(CKA.CKA_LABEL);

                        foreach (ObjectHandle handle in handles)
                        {
                            List<ObjectAttribute> oAttrs = session.GetAttributeValue(handle, attrs);   **//Error is getting here**
                        }

                        session.CloseSession();
                    }
                }

                pkcs11.Dispose();
            }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in [official documentation](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/tree/3.2.0#documentation) before you start using Pkcs11Interop you should get familiar at least with *"Chapter 2 - Scope"*, *"Chapter 6 - General overview"* and *"Chapter 10 - Objects"* of [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/master/doc/rsa-pkcs11-2.20).

Your code is first finding all objects regardless of their type (keys, certificates etc.) and then tries to read `CKA_VALUE` attribute of each individual object. `CKA_VALUE` is not valid attribute for all object types and I guess this might be causing your problems. Of course well behaving unmanaged PKCS#11 library would return `CKR_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_INVALID` error instead of segfaulting but there are many poor quality PKCS#11 libraries out there that do not handle such corner cases well.

I recommend you to first read mentioned chapters of specification and then change the search template passed to `FindAllObjects()` method to search only for specific object types you are really interested in.